# Maven warning: Artifact references the same file as the assembly destination file

Tags: java, maven

I'm getting the following maven warning while building my project:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:3.3.0:single (default) @ app-cl ---
[WARNING] Artifact: com.myorg:app-cl:jar:2021.08.2 build XXX references the same file as the assembly destination file. Moving it to a temporary location for inclusion.
```

What does it mean and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this warning is from this class: [AddArtifactTask](https://github.com/apache/maven-assembly-plugin/blob/3f444d799b16dc0ec1428fe99381adb4a649560d/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/assembly/archive/task/AddArtifactTask.java#L248). Apparently that was added as a [workaround](https://github.com/apache/maven-assembly-plugin/commit/a6c3602b238bc136c0171c3875869cc87539063b) to fix this [problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-282). Info from the ticket:

> This is due to the fact that the dependency set task tries to include the main project artifact as one of the dependencies. This causes a problem when there is no assembly ID and no classifier, because the archiver tries to include the destination file for the assembly in itself.